# Check if a list<StringCollection> contains list<string>

Tags: c#, search, data-structures

Given a `list<StringCollection>` how do most efficiently check whether all `string` are contained in any of the `StringCollection`s?

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create and initializes a new StringCollection.
        StringCollection myCol0 = new StringCollection();
        StringCollection myCol1 = new StringCollection();
        StringCollection myCol2 = new StringCollection();

        StringCollection SearchCol = new StringCollection();

        // Add a range of elements from an array to the end of the StringCollection.
        String[] myArr0 = new String[] { "RED", "car", "boat" };
        myCol0.AddRange( myArr0 );
        
        // Add a range of elements from an array to the end of the StringCollection.
        String[] myArr1 = new String[] { "Blue", "Goku", "Nappa" };
        myCol1.AddRange( myArr1 );
        
        // Add a range of elements from an array to the end of the StringCollection.
        String[] myArr2 = new String[] { "Yellow", "Winter", "Summer" };
        myCol2.AddRange( myArr2 );
        
        // Add a range of elements from an array to the end of the StringCollection.
        String[] myArr3 = new String[] { "Yellow", "Blue", "RED" };
        SearchCol.AddRange( myArr3 );
        
        List<StringCollection> a = new List<StringCollection>();
        a.Add(myCol0);
        a.Add(myCol1);
        a.Add(myCol2);
    }
}
```

In this case I want to know whether the strings in `SearchCol` is contained within the stringcollections stored in `List<StringCollection> a`

In this case I just like to know which of the searchCol strings is not included in the `List<StringCollection> a`

The only way I see this it possible to do so is via  a double for loop?
Is there any datastructure that would be more efficient rather than an stringcollection?

Comment: What strings must be contained?

Comment: the strings specified in the `SearchCol`

Comment: FYI `StringColleciton` is a leftover from .Net 1 when there were no generics.  You really should use `List<string>` instead, so in the end you'd be dealing with a `List<List<string>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any datastructure that would be more efficient rather than
> an stringcollection

Efficient in what way? Of course you should normally use a `IEnumerable<string>`(like a `string[]` vor `List<string>`) since `StringCollection` is not generic.

But you can also use `StringCollection`, you have to cast each item from object to string:

```
var allStrings = a.SelectMany(c => c.Cast<string>());
var searchStrings = SearchCol.Cast<string>();
bool allSearchStringsAreContained = searchStrings.All(allStrings.Contains);
```

as for the "how do most efficiently", this simple approach is efficient, but if you have a large list of strings that you search or huge string lists, you could use a set based approach:

```
HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(searchStrings);
bool allSearchStringsAreContained = set.IsSubsetOf(allStrings);
```

Finally, if you want to ignore the case, so treat "RED" and "Red" same:

Approach 1:

```
bool allSearchStringsAreContained = searchStrings.All(s => allStrings.Contains(s, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Approach 2:

```
HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(searchStrings, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```